I'm trying to create a list of hwids for my project, I add the hwids to the panel, and I hope it returns all the hwids but it doesn't happen
HTTP = require "ssl.https"
KEY = GetTotalHashHWID() .. ""
local HWID = HTTP.request("https://gitlab.com/at/a/-/raw/main/HWID%20FAST%20MENU%0TETS")
                    function CheckKey(allah)
                        for _, keys in pairs(HWID) do
                            if allah == keys then
                                return true
                            end
                        end
                    end

I expected it to return all the hwid that were on the site
bad argument #1 to 'pairs' (table expected, got nil) in function 'CheckKey'
